# Multiple tables display php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am building a web page which has many albums. It will be displaying images when I click one of the albums.

ISSUE 1: The problem I am having now is that all images from different albums will be displayed when I click into only one of the album.

ISSUE 2: In the php file that is for after clicking the album. I want to display only one picture for only one product but my code seems not working correctly

t1.recordid = t2.categoryrecordid

t2.productrecordid = t3.productid

The structure of my MySQL table design: 
Category: 
[image]

Product:
[image]

Productimage:

[image]

The code for my album:

```
            <div class="row">
            <?php
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT recordid, catcode,title,imgfile,catdesc FROM category ORDER BY recordid DESC');
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    extract($row);
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">

                        <p><img src="./images/<?php echo $row['catcode']?>/<?php echo $row['imgfile']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="190px" height="160px" /></p>
                        <p><a class="page-header" href="collectionGallery.php?cat= <?php echo $row['catcode']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></p> <br/>
                    </div>       
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

The code for after I clicking to album(display images of that album):

```
       <div class="row">
        <?php
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT category.*, product.*, productimage.*  FROM category JOIN product ON product.categoryrecordid=category.recordid JOIN productimage ON productimage.productid=product.productrecordid');
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                extract($row);
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p><img src="./images/<?php echo $row['catcode'].'/'. $row['imagefilename']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="190px" height="160px" /></p>
                    <p><?php echo $row['productcode'].' Price:'.$row['price']; ?></a></p>
                </div>       
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your SQL query is selecting every record, not just the one that was clicked on.  What you're looking for is called a `WHERE` clause: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html  Basically you need to identify specifically the record you want to display instead of just displaying all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how should I change in order to allow each of the album only shows the images that they belong to. I have edit the questions the things on top.

Comment: To display images as per Albums you need to use `WHERE` and few other  changes such as adding few tables to database `ELSE` if you wish i can send you a small example related to this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can I take a look at the example ?As I don't quite understand this, my email is zzzzzzhuigrey@hotmail.com.

Comment: ok and i will also be posting this answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So There is a similar example of the code Which can help you to understand.
but this is in `Mysqli Object oriented` as i myself learning `PDO`. But i'm sure this will give to preety good understanding .

Here i'm using PHP Object oriented with Mysqli prepared Statement

1) Create a table in database with name : albums

[image: albums table]

2) Create a table in database with name : productimg

[image: productimg table]

3) INDEX PAGE: index.php

```
    <?php
    include('products.php');
$newprod =  new products();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PHP MYSQL SHOW ALBUMS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb" style="width:100px;">
            <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
            <?php $newprod->showAlbums(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

4)this file displays album and product image : products.php

```
 <?php
    class products{
        private $link;

        function __construct(){
            $this->link = new mysqli('localhost','root','admin','codexworld');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
        }

        function showAlbums(){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            if($sql->prepare("SELECT pname,album_name,product_code FROM albums")){
                $sql->bind_result($pname,$albumname,$pcode);
                $sql->execute();
                while($sql->fetch()){
            ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="displproduct.php?pcode=<?php echo $pcode;?>"><img src="albumimages/<?php echo $albumname;?>" alt="<?php echo $pname; ?>" class="" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                        <h4>ALBUM :<strong><?php echo $pname;?></strong></h4></a>
                    </div>
            <?php   
                }
            }
        }

        function showproducts($productcode){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            if($sql->prepare("SELECT productname,productid,image FROM productimg WHERE productid = ?")){
                $sql->bind_param('s',$productcode);
                $sql->bind_result($pname,$pid,$img);
                $sql->execute();
                while($sql->fetch()){
            ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="productimg/<?php echo $img;?>" alt="<?php echo $pname; ?>" class="" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                        <h4>Product Image :<strong><?php echo $pname;?></strong></h4>
                    </div>
            <?php   
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

5)This file displays products : displproduct.php

```
 <?php
    include('products.php');
    $newprod =  new products();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PHP MYSQL SHOW ALBUMS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if(isset($_GET['pcode'])){
                    $productcode = $_GET['pcode'];
                    $newprod->showproducts($productcode);
                }   
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using mysqli prepare , php object oriented and PDO will help you to create neat looking , code manageable and solve complex problems .